# Unity C# instantiating "position + x, y, z"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a character that uses a weapon and I currently have it set to spawn on my character's position. I want that position to be my character plus a little bit to the right (x-axis). I have no clue how to do this and couldn't find the answer on google. I am a beginner so please be specific. Here is my code:

```
public float speed = 2f;
Animator anim;
private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
public float jumpHeight = 20f;
public GameObject weapon;
private Vector2 playerPos;
public GameObject player;

private void Start()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    playerPos = player.transform.position;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(1f * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
    {
        anim.SetInteger("State", 3);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(-1f * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
    {
        anim.SetInteger("State", 4);
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.P))
    {
        rb2d.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpHeight);
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
    {
        Instantiate(weapon, playerPos, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -40));
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add an empty object on your player and use that's transform as a reference.

Comment: You should try replacing (or at least reduce) the amount of if clause. Take a look at [Delagate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/), [Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action) and [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity, `Transform.position` is a `Vector3`. You can add two `Vector3` together with the `+` operator:

```
Vector3 result = myVectorA + myVectorB
// or
Vector3 result = new Vector3(5,6,7) + new Vector3(10,0,0) // result is (15,6,7)
```

To add to the playerPos's `x` value - you need to add a full Vector3 that just has the necessary translation as it's `x` value.

```
playerPos + new Vector3(100, 0, 0)
```

Details on Unity's vector arithmetic can be found here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnderstandingVectorArithmetic.html

And this answer on Unity explains why you cannot also just assign directly into `playerPos.x`: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/600421/how-to-change-xyz-values-in-a-vector3-properly-in.html

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem and I learned something new.